# How to select a link that contains an instance of a class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

right now the source code of my page has the following structure:

```
<span id='648746' class='topic'>linkedin
<a href='' class='hidden unblacklist' onclick='return false'>Restore</a>
<a href='' class='blacklist' onclick='return false'>[X]</a>
</span><br />
```

On pageload, the link with text "Restore" is hidden. When the user clicks the link, I want to add the `hidden` class to the link that was just clicked, and then I want to remove the `hidden` class from the other link in the `<span></span>`. I can get the first part to work, but I am having difficulty with the second part. Here is my attempt:

```
$(this).addClass("hidden");
console.log($(this).closest("span"));
$(this).closest("span").hasClass("unblacklist")[0].removeClass("hidden");
```

One of the biggest difficulties of this is that the other link has two classes: "hidden" and "unblacklist". I think I would know how to do it for one class, but the game changes for two classes.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: So many answers. All of them work, too! Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution would use `toggleClass()`:

```
$(this).parent().children().toggleClass('hidden');
```

Answer (score 1):

use .siblings():

```
$(this).addClass("hidden").siblings().removeClass("hidden");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/), which either returns all siblings in the DOM or accepts a jQuery filter.

```
$(this).addClass("hidden");
$(this).siblings('a.unblacklist').removeClass("hidden");
```

Just add this code to the click() handler of your link.

Answer (score 0):

You're third line is wrong.  Try:

```
$(this).closest("span").find(".unblacklist").removeClass("hidden");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('a.blacklist').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('hidden').siblings('a.unblacklist').removeClass('hidden');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `prev` method if the "Restore" link will always come before the "[X]" link.

```
$(this).addClass("hidden");
$(this).prev().removeClass("hidden");
```

Answer (score 0):

[hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) only tells if an element exposes a class. It returns a boolean value, not a jQuery object, so you cannot chain it.

You're looking for the [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/):

```
$(this).closest("span").find(".unblacklist").removeClass("hidden");
```

That said, a pattern often used in your situation is to remove the `hidden` class first, by matching the elements that expose it, then add it to the element of your choice:

```
$(this).closest("span").find(".hidden").removeClass("hidden");
$(this).addClass("hidden");
```

(The above assumes that your markup can be more complicated than the example in your question, so it refrains from using [siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to match the other anchor element.)